# java tells that can not find symbol

Tags: java

I am studying core Java myself. I wrote a Java program, and I got one error:

> ...cannot find symbol "refc"

but it *is* already declared as object reference... Can anyone explain that?

```
import java.io.*;

class contactmain {
    int count = 0;
    int[] a = new int[5];

    contactmain() {
        System.out.println("a");
        a[count] = count+1;
        count++;
    }
}

class contact {

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int y = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i<10) {
            contactmain refc = new contactmain();//create the instance of that class
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(refc.a[i]);
    }
}
```

In the last statement, I got an error {refc.a[i]} that it cannot find symbol. Please, help me.

Comment: Class names should start with an uppercase character, according to the Java conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope matters, you're declaring variable inside a `while(..){ }` and trying to access outside of the loop, change the code to:

```
while(i<10)
{
   contactmain refc=new contactmain();
   i++;
   System.out.println(refc.a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `refc` scope is limited inside the `while`.

To let it works, you could move your `System.out.println(refc.a[i]);` inside the `while` so the compiler will know the existence of `refc`

[What is a "variable scope"?](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm)

> Variable scope refers to the accessibility of a variable.
>
> The rule 1 is that variables defined in a block are only accessible
>   from within the block. The scope of the variable is the block in which
>   it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring contactmain refc inside a block, which in this case is a `while` block statement. This means that this reference will be avaiable for use only inside the scope of this block (because this blocks have their own stack of memory, everything defined inside them can be used only there)
So you have

```
while(i<10)
     {
        contactmain refc=new contactmain();
        i++;
      }
```

You can use        `System.out.println(refc.a[i]);`  only inside it. If you which to utilize this object reference outside the block, you should declare it before entering the block. For example:

```
contact main refc = null;
while(i<10)
         {
            refc=new contactmain();
            i++;
          }
System.out.println(refc.a[i]);
```

NOTE: Using lower case for naming is a bad practice. You should go with Camel-Case. Please refere to: [Variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) | [Naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)